# Trying to see if there's a better way to structure this query with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

So far this is the best way I've come up with do do this query in mySQL but I just wanna make sure there's not a more efficient way to do this with joins, or if this is more or less not gunna kill preformance.

```
SELECT r.CAMPAIGN_ID as ID, ref.VALUE as VALUE, SUM(CLICKS_IN) as cin, SUM(CLICKS_OUT) as cout, SUM(SALES) as sin 
FROM (
    SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS_IN, 0 AS CLICKS_OUT, 0 AS SALES FROM CLICKS_IN WHERE LANDER = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID
    UNION
    SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID, 0 AS CLICKS_IN, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS_OUT, 0 AS SALES FROM CLICKS_OUT WHERE LANDER = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID
    UNION
    SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID, 0 AS CLICKS_IN, 0 AS CLICKS_OUT, SUM(REVENUE) AS SALES FROM CONVERSIONS WHERE LANDER = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID ) as r
INNER JOIN
    CLICKS_CAMPAIGN as ref ON ref.ID = r.CAMPAIGN_ID
GROUP BY ID, VALUE
```

Most of the join options I've tried lose cases where there's clicks and no sales, sales and no clicks etc, and this is the only way I've figured out that doesn't lose any cases without using sub-queries.

Comment: UNIONs and JOINs are generally not interchangeable; they are for different goals.

Comment: I mean I just feel like casting 2\3 of the fields as 0 in the other queries then doing a sum operation can't be the most elegant solution.

Comment: I see what you mean, not sure if it is "better" than a UNION, but I will post a JOIN version of your query in a few minutes.

Comment: This is a pretty common way to write queries like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need aggregate values from multiple one-to-many relations at once, each aggregation needs to performed in a subquery *(or it can be done in a UNION like your original query; as Barmar pointed out, your query is actually a fairly common form for a query retrieving this kind of data)*

```
SELECT cc.ID, cc.VALUE, cIn.CLICKS_IN, cOut.CLICKS_OUT, cSales.SALES
FROM CLICKS_CAMPAIGN AS cc 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS_IN 
           FROM CLICKS_IN 
           WHERE LANDER = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? 
           GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID
          ) AS cIn ON cIn.CAMPAIGN_ID = cc.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT BIN_IP) AS CLICKS_OUT
           FROM CLICKS_OUT 
           WHERE LANDER = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? 
           GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID
          ) AS cOut ON cOut.CAMPAIGN_ID = cc.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAMPAIGN_ID, SUM(REVENUE) AS SALES 
           FROM CONVERSIONS 
           WHERE LANDER = ? AND TIME BETWEEN ? AND ? 
           GROUP BY CAMPAIGN_ID
          ) AS cSales ON cSales.CAMPAIGN_ID = cc.ID
GROUP BY cc.ID, cc.VALUE
;
```

This is not exactly the same as your original query, as you will get all "campaigns", even ones without "clicks" or sales; but if that is important; you can add a WHERE or HAVING with
`cIn.CLICKS_IN IS NOT NULL OR cOut.CLICKS_OUT IS NOT NULL OR cSales.SALES IS NOT NULL`